# CodeIgniter Curl Library Capturing Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve an error when my CI curl request fails.  However, I cant seem to get `$this->curl->error_code` or `$this->curl->error_string` to output any data. I am trying to make a request to an API and I am breaking the URL to force an error.

```
$api_url = "http://breamkebreakmedfd.com";

$this->curl->create($api_url);
$this->curl->execute();
echo($this->curl->error_string);
```

I get no error when I echo the error.

Comment: What cURL library are you using? [This one](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Curl_library)?

Comment: Are the required libraries installed? that is libcurl and php with cURL enabled?

Comment: Yes i am using the CI curl lib.

Comment: libraries are installed and curl is working its just not returning any error msg if the request fails.

Comment: So looks like in the CI Curl lib when the request fails its resetting the default variables and vars like $this->curl->error_code are being reset to null.  Line 309 in the curl lib.  When I comment out that line I am then able to get error_code and error_string.